# ASP.NET MVC Play Audio Files

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, accessibility

we have a requirement to play a audio file once the user logs on to the Portal. If they click on Audio file we need to set the status "listened" to true. The portal is built using ASP.NET MVC 3.0.

This is to cater the requirement for disabled users or people who can't read but can listen.

if anyone has already done this before, could you pleaes guide me through how this can be achieved (architecture) please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing MVC related that works with audio files.  You will need to embed some kind of player into your HTML to play the audio files.  Perhaps something silverlight or flash based.